# How to make base class's operators visible with variadic number of base classes (please see code below)?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

What is the best way to expose operators from base class like the following code is trying to do. I suppose with one or two base classes we'd use `using` syntax, but with a variadic number of base classes, is something like `using Base<Ts>::operator=...;` possible?

```
template <typename T, typename Derived>
class varU
{
    protected:
    varU() = default;

    Derived& operator=(T val)
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->set(val);
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

template <typename ...Ts>
class var : public varU<Ts, var<Ts...>>...
{
    // using varU<Ts, var<Ts...>>::operator=...;  // Something like this?

    private:
    template <typename T>
    void set(const T& v)
    {
    }
};
```

EDIT:

Seems like `using Base<Ts>::operator=...` is indeed the correct syntax which I was looking for in C++17. I was using the wrong standard version and expecting C++17. Since this was my guess, I didn't dig deep.

Comment: You are asking if it is possible. DId you try it? Did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, what you want to achieve with your code, so perhaps you want to go a bit more into detail in your question.

But regarding your question in the code-comment, the answer is yes, it's possible in C++17.
If you actually want to use your operators, you also have to declare the `varU` class a friend of `var`:

The following compiles on gcc and clang:

```
template <typename T, typename Derived>
class varU
{
    protected:
    varU() = default;

    Derived& operator=(T val)
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->set(val);
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

template <typename ...Ts>
class var : public varU<Ts, var<Ts...>>...
{
    template <typename T, typename Derived>
    friend class varU;

    public:
     using varU<Ts, var<Ts...>>::operator=...;  // Something like this?

    private:
    template <typename T>
    void set(const T& v)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    var<int, float> x;
    x = 5;
    x = 5.f;

    return 0;
}
```

See [live code here.](https://godbolt.org/z/m9MMN_)